# There was no endpoint listening at net.tcp://localhost:10001 that could accept the message

Tags: wcf, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

I'm having a problem when moving a WCF service from Windows 2003 Server to Windows 2008 Server. This service communicates between a web site and a windows service on the same server.  The service runs with the below configurations on both 2003 Server and locally on Windows 7 computers.

On the 2008 server, I'm getting the following error message

**Exception Type**: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException

**Message:** There was no endpoint listening at net.tcp://localhost:10001/DCFDirectCert/SecurityService that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.

**Configuration for Web Site**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
                      logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="DirectCertBindingConfig">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="DirectCert.Services.DirectCertSecurityService.BindingConfig" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                 openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false"
                 transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="1000000" maxConnections="10"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:10001/DirectCert/SecurityService" binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="DirectCert.Services.DirectCertSecurityService.BindingConfig"
                contract="IDirectCertSecurityService" name="IDirectCertSecurityService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Configuration for Windows Service**

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
                      logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="DirectCert.Services.DirectCertSecurityService.BindingConfig">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DirectCert.Services.DirectCertSecurityService.Behavior"
               name="DirectCertSecurityService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="DirectCert.Services.DirectCertSecurityService.BindingConfig"
                  contract="IDirectCertSecurityService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:10001/DirectCert/SecurityService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.msmq://localhost/private/DirectCert" binding="netMsmqBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="DirectCert.Services.DirectCertMatchService.BindingConfig"
                contract="IDirectCertMatchService" name="DirectCertMatchServiceClient" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myBehaviorConfiguration">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="DirectCert.Services.DirectCertSecurityService.Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer />
          <serviceTimeouts />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I can see is, that the security-mode of both bindings is not the same (transport vs. none).